# Extends Session Token ExpiresAt

Tags: parse-platform

I wanted to create a cloud code function that help me change the date of the ExpiresAt Field value of Session Token in Parse Server. Is there any way for doing this? or any API that I can refer to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Ends up I answer my own question. After sometimes, I found that I can create a CloudCode Function as below for extending Session Token, HOpe this helps others.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("extendSessionToken", function(request, response)
{
    req({
        method: 'GET',
        url: process.env.SERVER_URL + "/sessions/me",
        headers:
        {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': process.env.APP_ID,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': process.env.REST_API_KEY,
            'X-Parse-Session-Token': request.headers["x-parse-session-token"],
            'X-Parse-Master-Key' : process.env.MASTER_KEY
        }        
    }, function (error, httpResponse, body) 
    {
        var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
        DLog.info(JSON.stringify(jsonBody));
        if(error)
        {            
            handleResponseReturn(response, 1, error);
        }
        else if(jsonBody.error)
        {            
            handleResponseReturn(response, 1, jsonBody.error);
        }
        else
        {            
            var newSessionYear = new Date();
            newSessionYear.setFullYear(newSessionYear.getFullYear() + 1);
            var newSessionBody = {
                'expiresAt': Parse._encode(newSessionYear)
            }

            DLog.info("New ExpiresAt: " + JSON.stringify(newSessionBody));
            req({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: process.env.SERVER_URL + "/sessions/" + jsonBody.objectId,
                    headers:
                    {
                        'X-Parse-Application-Id': process.env.APP_ID,
                        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': process.env.REST_API_KEY,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                        'X-Parse-Session-Token': request.headers["x-parse-session-token"],
                        'X-Parse-Master-Key' : process.env.MASTER_KEY
                    },
                    body:  JSON.stringify(newSessionBody) 
                }, function (error, httpResponse, body) 
                {
                    var jsonResult = JSON.parse(body);
                    if(error)
                        handleResponseReturn(response, 1, error);
                    else if(jsonBody.error)
                        handleResponseReturn(response, 1, jsonBody.error);
                    else
                        handleResponseReturn(response, 0, body);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps those who are facing the same problems. Feel free to take this and modify as you like.